# Isotope grid breaks on browser resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I am trying to create a 3 column grid using Twitter Bootstrap and Isotope. However, when I resize the browser to be narrow enough to force the layout into a single column mode, isotope fails leaving large vertical and horizontal spaces.

#### Normal when not one column

[image: Normal]

#### Broken when one column

[image: Broken]

As you can see in the above image, there are large vertical spaces and also the first cell doesn't expand to 100% width.

[Here's my Codepen.](http://codepen.io/adarshr/pen/QbbyoQ)

HTML:

```
<html lang="en" class="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>isotope</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="masonry row">
                <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">1. One</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam auctor metus et porta facilisis. </p>
                        <p>Aenean congue lorem accumsan erat tempor, eu tempus ex tristique.</p>
                        <small class="text-muted">27 Nov 2014</small>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#">auctor</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">2. Two</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>Duis mattis risus quis purus gravida lobortis. Donec pharetra, mi in consectetur ornare, elit felis luctus nibh, vitae elementum dui felis blandit neque. </p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elementum venenatis massa, vitae varius metus commodo sed. Vivamus et ante at nisi scelerisque consectetur. Praesent semper lacus vitae nibh venenatis mollis a eu nunc. Donec id erat lacus.</p>
                        <small class="text-muted">03 Nov 2007</small>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#">elit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">3. Three</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>Duis mattis risus quis purus gravida lobortis. Donec pharetra, mi in consectetur ornare, elit felis luctus nibh, vitae elementum dui felis blandit neque. Proin egestas congue dui id porta. Donec luctus ex sit amet dui rhoncus, quis dignissim odio accumsan.</p>
                        <small class="text-muted">19 Sep 2006</small>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#">venenatis</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">4. Four</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>Integer commodo pharetra lorem vel sollicitudin. Nunc in euismod magna. Nam varius turpis luctus consequat bibendum. Proin vehicula cursus dui. Duis ut nunc et dui volutpat mattis id sed ex. </p>
                        <small class="text-muted">19 Sep 2006</small>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#">luctus</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.1.1/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.masonry {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.item {
    margin-right: -1px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.cell {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    border: 1px solid #F6F6F6;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var isotope = new Isotope('.masonry', {
  itemSelector: '.item',
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: '.item'
  }
});

isotope.layout();
```

When I reload the browser when already in a narrow viewport, the vertical gaps even out but the first cell still doesn't expand to be 100%.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue right here.. did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: Nope. Glad I'm not alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I found that defining the following CSS at least solves the horizontal issue:

```
@media (max-width: 991.9999px) {
    .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

So what I found out is that isotope/masonry needs to have a width set to the *.item* element.

However, I will try to update my solution regarding the vertical issue as soon as possible..

Comment: When adding this code to your codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPgBjG) I noticed no actual problem. It seems to be that simple :)

Comment: Yes, that seems to work quite well. I am impressed with your solution :-) Will do a bit more testing around this and accept your answer. We should probably raise an issue on their GitHub page.

Comment: @adarshr Did you find time to verify the acceptance of this answer?