# Bootstrap Grid System: Reset Vertical Space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a responsive newsfeed page using Bootstrap. There is nothing wrong with the mobile version, as you can see in the screenshot below.

The problem occurs when the screen gets larger, and I would like to display the elements in two separate columns. When one of the two top elements in both columns is vertically larger than the other, the third element will be pushed down as you can see on the second image. The goal is to remove the vertical space between A and C.

Using two different rows inside a large row (representing the two columns) is no option, because the order of the elements is important, as well in the mobile version as in the desktop version.

Currently each element has as class 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'.

See JSFiddle for complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/4v40x5a3/

```
<div class="row>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

**Mobile version example (no issues) :**

[image]

**Desktop version example(vertical space issue) :**

[image]

Comment: Create demo / show us relevant code

Comment: That will happen, because that's how the gird system works.

Comment: I suggest you look in [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is important and a solution (like the one @AlexG provided) is no option, then I would recommend using the brilliant [Isotope/masonry plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).
I used it in the exact same context.

Download, include it and then add the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 item"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 item"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 item"></div>
</div>
```

**..and in your *scripts.js* or before the body closure tag:**

```
// init isotope layout
$isotopeContainer   =   jQuery('div.container > div.row');
$isotopeContainer.isotope({
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: '.item'
    }
});
```

**..and in CSS:**

You might consider defining a width for the column elements for your mobile view - otherwise they might appear in different widths. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355318/isotope-grid-breaks-on-browser-resize/29852240#29852240))

```
@media (max-width: 991.9999px) {
    .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

**Additionally, if you use the collapsible functionality of bootstrap:**

```
// update isotope layout
jQuery('div.container').find('div.tools > a.collapse').on('click.collapse.data-api', function (event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('div.container > div.row').isotope( 'layout');
    }, 350);
});
```

Worked like a charm in my case, let me know if you need further help..

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Have you any idea if it is possible to disable the transition while resizing the window? When going from a large screen size to a mobile screen size, the items are showing behind each other and move to their correct position afterwards. It is not that important, just an option I would like to know if it is possible or not? It would be even more beautiful if they would never go behind each other. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @CodingMonkeys Nice to hear! To achieve this just do the following in your Isotope init. function: `$isotopeContainer.isotope({transitionDuration: 0, ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget you can put rows into cols. Lets say you have 6 items in total. You just split the first half into the left col and the second half into the right col. The only issue you might have is that one col is a lot higher than the other one, might be caused by too many large content panels.

You could also simply just limit the height of your content. And show the full article on a seperate page

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        3 items here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        3 items here 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*.pull-left* and *.pull-right* will automatically fix them appropriately depending on the screen sizes.

Comment: Please can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same problem. James Cazetta's Isotope/Masonry solution will work. But here's a Javascript/jQuery hack I did. Seems to work.

"content-main" is equivalent to the "A" div in the question. 
"content-extra" is equivalent to the "B" div in the question.

```
 var bottom_div_changed = false;
 function fix_bottom_div() {
     if (window.innerWidth > 991) { // Replace 991 with desired screen size
         var $el = $('#content-main');
         var bottom = $el.position().top + $el.outerHeight(true);
         var $el = $('#content-extra');
         var top = $el.position().top;
         var diff = top - bottom;
         if (diff > 0) { // If you want more margin, use number bigger than 0.
             $el.css("margin-top", -diff);
             bottom_div_changed = true;
         };
     } else if (bottom_div_changed == true) { 
         // This can happen if the screen is resized to less than 991.
         var $el = $('#content-extra');
         $el.css("margin-top", 0);
     }
 };
 $(window).resize(function () {
     fix_bottom_div();
 });
 $(window).load(function() {
     fix_bottom_div();
 });
```